# VideoView и его ориентация

Tags: android, videoview

В приложении использую `VideoView`. В манифесте прописано `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`. При запуске приложения на планшетах с 4кой оно запускается, как и должно, в портретной ориентации, а видео проигрывается в ландшафте. Что сделать, чтобы видео проигрывалось в портретной ориентации?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо декларировать Activity как:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:label="My Activity"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

**Update**

Надо еще добавить  `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`  в теге `<Application>`

Comment: собственно, так и прописано, но это не помогает.

Comment: @monomi см. апдейт